# Subset all values from two columns that correspond to another column(s) in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, group-by, apply

I have a data frame with 4 columns

| ID1 | ID2 | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | zinc | sulfur |
| 1 | 2 | zinc | calcium |
| 1 | 2 | calcium | NA |
| 3 | 4 | carbon | iron |
| 3 | 4 | iron | iron |
| 3 | 4 | iron | carbon |

The first two columns will always correspond so I only essentially need to work with one of the ID columns in configurating this.

For each pair of IDs I want every value that corresponds to either of the IDs, and for it to only appear once.

So for the example above I want:

| ID1 | ID2 | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | zinc, sulfur, calcium |
| 3 | 4 | carbon, iron |

But a list might also work if it simply lists the amount of times each value (uniquely appears) for each ID.

What I eventually want is the number of times each Value appears in the dataset

eg:

| Value | Count |
| --- | --- |
| calcium | 1 |
| carbon | 1 |
| zinc | 1 |
| iron | 1 |
| sulfur | 1 |

I guess a list might be a better way to get to this endpoint, but I’m more well-versed in working with data frames. For now, I’m mostly interested in the first part (getting each value for the pair of IDs).

Comment: Why does calcium have a count of 2 in your intended output, if only `ID` == 1 has a value of calcium?

Comment: I did it quickly and mistakenly combined calcium and carbon. Edited it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` approach to solve your first problem.

First `group_by` your `ID` columns, then use `summarise` to `paste` and collapse them into single row of comma-separated string per `ID` pair (and also removes `NA` by `na.omit`).

Finally, `str_split` the comma separated string to remove duplicated elements, `paste` them back together, and `ungroup`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID1, ID2) %>% 
  summarize(Values = paste0(na.omit(Value1), ",", na.omit(Value2), collapse = ",")) %>% 
  mutate(Values = paste0(unique(sort(str_split(Values, ",", simplify = T))), collapse = ",")) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 × 3
    ID1   ID2 Values             
  <int> <int> <chr>              
1     1     2 calcium,sulfur,zinc
2     3     4 carbon,iron
```

#### Data

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "
ID1 ID2 Value1  Value2
1   2   zinc    sulfur
1   2   zinc    calcium
1   2   calcium NA
3   4   carbon  iron
3   4   iron    iron
3   4   iron    carbon")
```

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr` an option is also to `t`ranspose the 'Value' columns, get the `unique` and `paste` with `toString` after grouping

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 group_by(ID1, ID2) %>% 
 summarise(Values = toString(na.omit(unique(c(t(across(starts_with("Value"))))))), 
       
    .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
    ID1   ID2 Values               
  <int> <int> <chr>                
1     1     2 zinc, sulfur, calcium
2     3     4 carbon, iron
```

Comment: A slightly different option (one function less), with `unlist`: `toString(na.omit(unique(unlist(across(Value1:Value2)))))`

Comment: @Maël i  initially thought about that, but it returns the order differently as it seems from expected that OP want the row order to be kept

Comment: That's right! didn't see that

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```r
data.frame(table(unlist(df[, sapply(df, is.character)])))

     Var1 Freq
1 calcium    2
2  carbon    2
3    iron    4
4  sulfer    1
5    zinc    2
```

data

```r
df <- structure(list(ID1 = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3), ID2 = c(2, 2, 2, 4, 
4, 4), Value1 = c("zinc", "zinc", "calcium", "carbon", "iron", 
"iron"), Value2 = c("sulfer", "calcium", NA, "iron", "iron", 
"carbon")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
    ID1   ID2 Value1  Value2 
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  
1     1     2 zinc    sulfer 
2     1     2 zinc    calcium
3     1     2 calcium NA     
4     3     4 carbon  iron   
5     3     4 iron    iron   
6     3     4 iron    carbon
```

Answer (score 0):

Within `tidyverse` the process is to gather the value1 and value2 in a `tidy` dataset, `group_by` your id variables, and `summarize` using the concatenation of your string values.

```
library(tidyverse)

id1 <- c(1,1,1,3,3,3)
id2 <- c(2,2,2,4,4,4)
Value1 <- c("zinc", "zinc", "calcium", "carbon", "iron", "iron")
Value2 <- c("sulfer", "calcium", NA, "iron", "iron", "carbon")

df <- as_tibble(cbind(id1,id2,Value1,Value2))

df_cln <- df %>%
  gather(var, value, -id1, -id2, na.rm = T) %>%
  select(-var) %>%
  unique() %>%
  group_by(id1, id2) %>%
  summarise(minerals=paste0(value, collapse=","))

print(df_cln)

# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   id1 [2]
  id1   id2   minerals           
  <chr> <chr> <chr>              
1 1     2     zinc,calcium,sulfer
2 3     4     carbon,iron
```